# Span collapse/margin/padding while creating a subcaption?

Tags: css, html

please see this code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ap6vK/

```
span.Title{
    font-size: 100px;       
    color:#6495ed;
    border:1px solid black;
}

span.SubTitle{
    font-size: 30px;
    position:relative;
    top:23px;
    right:163px;
    color:#778899;
}

<span class="Title">
    Caption
    <span class="SubTitle">SubCaption</span>
</span>
```

I use two spans to create a subcaption. problem I have is that the outer span doesn't collapse. See the black border which extends too far? I would like to have the border cropped to the caption instead of remaining the size of the caption+subcaption next to each other instead of beneath each other. does any one know how to do this?

Comment: are you talking about the right side padding being too much making a lot of empty padding space at the right, making the right border go too much to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you mean the right padding is too much.  That's because any `position relative` with `left` and `top` set will be like, the element is as if it was there, but just shifted.  (meaning it occupies the real estate, but then shifted).  So that's why the extra padding at the right for your border.

you can look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/ap6vK/4/

it is using the inner span

```
position: absolute
```

and the outer span:

```
position: relative
```

This way, the inner span is placed, not by the normal flow and with the real estate not considered.  But to make it work, you have to make the outer span `position: relative` because the container must have any `position` that is set to something rather than the default value `static` so that the children element with `position: absolute` will be **relative** to this container.